# Is there a Demosaicing algorithm that discards the 2º Green pixel and produces a image without interpolation with 4x less resolution?

Tags: raw, demosaicing

that is it takes each four pixels RGBG ignores one of the greens and produces a single pixel from the 3(RGB), with no interpolation.

Comment: Yes, this algorithm clearly exists as you've just written it down. What were you wanting to use this algorithm for?

Comment: I just wanted to see the result of it, let's say I have a 20 Mp camera I get 5 Mp.  What is the easiest way to code such algoritm, as a part of some software plugin like darktable, or a python script that takes the raw and produces the tiff(I'm learning python)?

Comment: Hi Tito and welcome to Photo.SE. Could you indicate what you have tried already? Did you try googling [`python read camera raw file`](https://www.google.nl/search?q=python+read+camera+raw+file) for example? It's better if you do some research first and then, if things remain unclear, pose a question on the suitable StackExchange site.

Comment: [dcraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dcraw) runs from the command line, you can give options to output a tiff file without demosaicing. You can then easily apply your algorithm on that tiff file.

Comment: In theory doing what you propose will result in the R,G,B components being a half-pixel offset from each other. In practice I'll bet nobody would notice.

Comment: You'd probably get slightly better results averaging the two green pixels in each four pixel group rather than discarding one of them.

Comment: @MarkRansom, The spatial offsets of the RGB pixels are taken into account by standard de-mosaic algos. You should do the same producing a 5MP from a 20MP image. Also, consider Michael and Count's good points.

Comment: @doug I wrote such a downsampling algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129279/demosaicing-algorithm-that-contains-downsampling. It's more complex than the process described in the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom.  Nice. I haven't done that but I've used max length pseudorandom sequences to generate waveforms with equally spaced spectral amplitudes up to frequencies just under 1/4 Nyquist. This makes it pretty easy to extract MTF and chromatic aberration info. I just treated R,B and the two G's separately and looked a their relative phase offsets. This was some time back when I was looking at QA processes for screening lenses. I keep intending to do something similar to characterize the low pass nature of inkjet printing. Keeping below 1/4 Nyquist simplifies the poster's goal.

Answer (score 3):

The command line program [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) can *almost* do what you want. It does two things differently, though: it averages in both green pixels, and it also adjusts the color balance using its own internal algorithms. But, if you run it as `dcraw -h -T`, you get a TIFF file with just averaging and no interpolation — half-scale in both dimensions, so ¼ the overall area.

Here is the 1:1 pixel center crop from a random image from my working directory:

[image: dcraw -h]

(Apologies for the non-level horizon — I was on a boat.)

Here's the same image using AHD interpolation, `dcraw -q 3`, and the scaled down by half *without* further interpolation:

[image: dcraw -q 3]

Neither of these have any sharpening applied; feel free to try it. If you do, you'll find that if anything sharpening makes the AHD image's benefit even more clear. (As, for that matter, scaling it down with a less lossy approach.)

If you really want, it would surely be trivial to modify dcraw to skip the other green pixels, but I don't see any particular benefit.

For further reference, here's a conversion with Rawtherapee and its default "AMaZE" demosaicking algorithm, also resized to half-scale but this time with Lanczos resampling and with post-scaling sharpening added (which I may have overdone a bit looking now, but this is just meant to be a quick demo).

[image: raw therapee]

And as a final comparison, here's the out-of-camera JPEG (this is from a Pentax K-5ii):
[image: ooc resized]

(Resized and sharpened with a very quick unsharp mask, and then saved as PNG to avoid recompression artifacts.)

Comment: I think these two images illustrate well why we go to the trouble of demosaicing and interpolation. It's worth it both in terms of resolution and color accuracy.

Comment: @MichaelClark there's clearly a difference in sharpness between these two examples, but I don't see any color difference between them.

Comment: Look at the yellows, reds, and oranges. There's not much in the scene, but even at the small sizes you should be able to see a significant difference in the transitions between brighter and darker tones of the same hues.

Comment: I found your test very interesting.
I found however a clear benefit on the first image (dcraw -h one). Look at the top lights, green and red, on the center big boat down the big building arc, that colour and detail are not reflected in the next 3 images.